# ServerValue.increment doesn't work properly when Internet goes down

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, offline

The addition of `ServerValue.increment()` ([Add increment() for atomic field value increments #2437](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2437)) was a great news as it allows field values ​​to be increased atomically in Firebase RTDB.

I have an application that keeps inventories and this function has been key because it allows updating the inventory regardless of whether the user is offline at times. However, I started to notice that sometimes the function is executed twice, which completely misstates the inventory in the wrong way.

To isolate the problem I decided to do the following test, which shows that `ServerValue.Increment()` works wrong when the connection goes from Online to Offline:

1. Make a `for loop function` from 1 to 200:

   ```
   for (var i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
     testBloc.incrementTest(i);
     print('Pos: $i');
   }
   ```
2. The function `incrementTest(i)` must increment two variables: `position` (count from 1 in 1 up to 200) and `sum` (add 1 + 2 + 3, ..., + 200 which should result in 20,100)

   ```
       Future<bool> incrementTest(int value) async {    
        try {    

          db.child('test/position')
            .set(ServerValue.increment(1));     

          db.child('test/sum')
            .set(ServerValue.increment(value));     

        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }  


         return true;
    }
   ```

Note that db refers to the Firebase instance (`FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()`)

With this, comes the tests:

### Test 1: 100% Online. PASSED

The function works properly, reaching the two variables to the correct result (in the Firebase console):

> position: 200
>
> sum: 20100

### Test 2: 100% Offline. PASSED

To do this I used a physical device in airplane mode, then I executed the `for loop function`, and when the function finished executing I deactivated airplane mode and checked the result in the firebase console, which was satisfactory:

> position: 200
>
> sum: 20100

## Test 3: Start Online and then go to Offline. FAILED

It is a typical operating scenario when the **Internet Connection goes down**. Even worse when the connections are intermittent, you are traveling on a subway or you are in a low coverage site for which Offline Persistence is a desired feature. To simulate it, what I did was run the `for loop function` in online mode, and before it finished, I put the physical device in airplane mode. Later I went Online to finish the test and see the results on the Firebase console. The results obtained are incorrect in all cases. Here are some of the results:

[image: Increment is Executed Twice many times]

As you can see, the Increment was erroneously repeated 10, 18 and 9 times more.

How can I avoid this behavior?

Is there any other way to increment atomically a number in Firebase that works properly online / Offline ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

That's an interesting edge-case in the increment behavior. Between the client and the server neither can be certain whether the increment was executed or not, so it ends up being retried from the client upon the reconnect. This problem can only occur with the increment operation as far as I can tell, as all the other write operations are idempotent except for transactions, but those don't work while offline.

It **is** possible to ensure each increment happens only once, but it'll take some work:

1. First, add a nonce to write operation that unique identifies this operation. You can use a push key for this, but any other UUID also works fine. Combine this with your original `set()` call into a single multi-path `update` call, writing the nonce to a top-level node with a server-side timestamp as its value.
2. Now in your security rules for the top-level location, only allow the write if there is no existing data. This ensures the secondary writes you're seeing get rejected, and since security rules are checked across multi-path updates as a whole, the faulty increment will get rejected too.
3. You'll probably want to periodically clean up the node with nonce keys, based on the timestamp value in there. It won't matter for performance (since you're never searching here outside of during the cleanup), but may help control the storage cost for the nonces.

I haven't used this approach for this specific use-case yet, but have done it for others. If you'd include a client-side retry, the above essentially builds your own multi-path transaction mechanism, which is what I needed it for in the past. But since you don't need that here, it's simpler without that.

Comment: Mmmmm @puf. It looks very interesting. In my real use-case, I'm using multipath and I'm writing / setting an object that includes a push key as follows: `'bodega/1/salidaAlimento/$pushKeyId': salidaAlimento.toJson()`. Can I define the Security Rule you suggest based on this location? How can I do that?

Comment: It doesn't really matter where the nonce is written, as long as it's unique and identifies the individual increment operation. The security rule for that location would be (at least): `".write": "!data.exists()"`.

Comment: @puf, you are great. I've been doing tests and it works!!!

Comment: Nice!    I'd love to see what you ended up with, maybe as a self-answer :)

Comment: Ok, of course. I have just done it!!!

Comment: I'm so sorry @puf. I've been testing with a few more people and it didn't work as expected, I keep getting duplication errors on increment. In this case, I reassembled the original skeleton of the question and indeed I still have problems (my suggested answer is wrong). I think I am making a mistake when setting up the Firebase security rules. Where do I need to locate the rule? How can I see when Firebase reject the write operation?

Comment: Darn! Sorry to hear about the trouble. Your rules and write look good at first glance, but I'll look again tomorrow with fresher eyes.

Comment: It seems that the problem with the rules is related to the cascade of the .write into the deeper paths. I will continue tomorrow.

Comment: @puf. I updated my answer using .validate instead of .write. The above, given that the rules are transmitted in cascade, it is very likely that at the height of the path where the increment is, there is already a previous rule that allows writing and therefore prevails over the new rule. I don't know if it has implications in terms of performance or something else. What do you think of this change?

Comment: Oooh... good catch. `.write` rules are indeed OR'ed and permission cascades down, so as soon as you have permission on a level you can write everything below it (no matter the rules there). `.validate` rules are AND'ed, so will work even if you have more condition on other levels. Note that `.validate` rules aren't triggered on a deletion (while `.write` rules are), but I don't think that is a problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @puf answer, you can proceed as follows:

```
  Future<bool> incrementTest(int value, int dateOfToday) async {

    var id = db.push().key;

    Map<String, dynamic> _updates = {
      'test/position':            ServerValue.increment(1), 
      'test/sum':                 ServerValue.increment(value),  
      'test/nonce/$id':           dateOfToday,
    };

      db.child('previousPath').update(_updates)
         .catchError((error) => print('Increment Duplication Rejected ${error.message}'));

    return true;
  }
```

Then, in Firebase Security Rules, you need to add a rule in `test/nonce/id` location. Something as follows:

```
{
  "previousPath": {
    "test": {
      ".read": "auth != null",  //It depends on your root rules
      ".write": "auth != null", //It depends on your root rules
      "nonce": {
        "$nonce_id": {
          ".validate": "!data.exists()" //THE MAGIC IS HERE
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this way, when the device tries to write to the database again (wrongly), Firebase will reject it since it already had a write with that same ID before.

I hope it serves someone else!!!