# Firestore Batchwrites is updating Fieldvalue Increment multiple times if device is switched from offline to online and clear running my application

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Today I found an error about Firestore Batchwrite in my stock control application.

My database structure was designed to store the order detail information in one collection (`orders`) and in other collection (`report_monthly` for count purposes) for monthly reports, I stored the quantity information such as total no of stocks, price, and debts.

The problem was this morning I make offline orders of stocks of about 20-25 orders. After I switch my phone from offline to online instantly, I can see the numbers are increasing (clearly firebase is updating the data) but I suddenly clear the app from working like clear recent apps in the android system. Then when I re-run(open) my app, these data are incorrect. Although the data in order collection(`orders`) is correct, the report number of quantity value in the monthly collection(`report_monthly`) was somehow repeated increment.

I tested this process multiple times with my friend and still facing the problems. I also tested without using BatchWrite. In that case, I can still see the issues but some of Fieldvalue increments are right and some are wrong not like in BatchWrite which is the whole list of Fieldvalue increments is wrong.

Can someone suggest to me how can I handle this kind of problem?

Comment: While the `increment` operation is atomic, it may indeed not be idempotent in unreliable network conditions. If that is indeed the case, your only solution would bo to use your own nonce-like values similar to what I showed for the Realtime Database here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69629858/servervalue-increment-doesnt-work-properly-when-internet-goes-down

Comment: Thanks. Now it is working well. I make a nonce collection with UUID as a document ID and make a security rule for only nonce collection because I think I can only get that UUID sent by the user from nonce document creation. Right? As a Batchwrite when I get the missing permission in the nonce, it disallowed the increment in other collections. So, I'm thinking this method can't be applied to a single write increment (not in a Batchwrite) because I can't get that UUID (obviously in other col) to use in increment collection condition. I'm just checking if I'm missing some kind of important part.